# Showing that $\int_0^\pi\frac{x\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx=3\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, periods

> Prove, without evaluating the integrals that:
> $$\int_0^\pi\frac{x\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx=3\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx$$

Originally I posted this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3490404/515527) on MSE, however it's still unanswered.

As mentioned on the above link, both of the integrals are already evaluated independently (the integral from RHS can be found as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050696/515527) after substituting $\tan \frac{x}{2} \to x$), so I want to show this equality without calculating those integrals explicitly.

What seems quite interesting is that removing the $x$ from the numerator gives:
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx$$
This can be shown quite easily without calculating any of the integrals, so that's what I seek to see by asking this question.

Comment: "Prove, without evaluating the integrals...."   Isn't proving these equalities the **definition** of evaluating the integrals?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I think what is meant is the analogous to the following: The last integral equation in the post can be seen by periodicity of $\dfrac{\ln(1-\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}$. Applying the periodicity of the function requires no actual evaluation of the integrals. Similarly, one could establish integral equalities just by a clever substitution, but not actually evaluating anything. I hope I captured the spirit here.

Comment: @C.Caruvana Yes, that's what I'm looking for.// I'm not sure how to rewrite the first part in a better way. But mainly in the first link it's shown that $\int_0^\pi\frac{x\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx=-\frac{3\pi^3}{8}$ and in the second linked post that $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{x\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x}dx=-\frac{\pi^3}{8}$ so the aim is to show this equality (but without using the results).

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such questions. The command of Maple `with(IntegrationTools):
simplify(Combine(Change(Int(x*log(1 - sin(x))/sin(x), x = Pi/2 .. Pi), x = Pi - y) + Int(y*log(1 - sin(y))/sin(y), y = 0 .. Pi/2)));` performs  `Pi*int(ln(1 - sin(y))/sin(y), y = 0 .. Pi/2)`

Comment: @user64494 Pardon my density, but I'm not sure how to finish the argument based on this computation. It seems like what this establishes is that $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\ln(1-\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}\ dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \int_0^\pi \frac{\ln(1-\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}\ dx.$ How can I complete the desired equality from here?

Comment: Bounties should not be used to prevent a question from being closed.

Comment: @StefanKohl - I don't understand your remark, I don't see votes to close - are there such? Despite some commenter remarks, this question seems nontrivial to me (certainly not a simple matter of symmetries). Possibly it won't have a good answer, but I don't think it's a trivial question.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt The question was flagged for bounty abuse to prevent closure, by a user whom I believe can judge the question. Maybe he was mistaken anyway. While a question has a bounty, one cannot vote to close -- and the question lacked a top-level tag, which generally reduces visibility. I added such tag. If the question doesn't gather close votes now, the OP can simply start the bounty anew.

Comment: @StefanKohl - I see. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the Fourier series of the integrands?

Comment: @MarkWildon I don't know what's the Fourier series of the integrand, but I tried a workaround using the Fourier series of  $\ln(1-\cos x)$, namely $=-\ln 2 -2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n x)}{n}$, that fails for the LHS integral.

Comment: I am adding the tag for periods.  If you set $u=\arccos(x)$, you get an almost algebraic expression for the integral, which can then be made into an algebraic double integral.